# Switching columns of two tables

Tags: tables, arrays

I need to switch the 1st and 2nd columns. I can't figure out where to put the A! The table on top is the original. The one on the bottom is what I am working on.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, onecolumn]{article}
\usepackage{multicol, multirow, array}
\usepackage{tensor}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{bm}

\geometry{tmargin=1in,bmargin=1in,lmargin=1in,rmargin=1in}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\fancyhead{}
\lhead{}
\chead{\fontsize{7}{12} \selectfont \textbf{Remarks on Notation, Size, and Shape of the Operating Matricies and Row and Column Vectors in ROSE} \\ \fontsize{6}{9} \selectfont Carl Ledbetter 3 June 2019}
\rhead{}

\title {Remarks on Notation, Size, and Shape of the Operating Matricies and Row and Column Vectors in ROSE}
\author{Carl Ledbetter}
\date{3 June 2019}
\thispagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\[
 \begin{array}{|>{\centering\bigstrut$}p{3cm}<{$}|>{\centering$}p{3cm}<{$}|c|}
    \hline
     & &  \\
    A & & \hat b \\
     & &  \\
    \cdashline{1-1} \cdashline{3-3} 
    \bar c &\multirow{-4}{*}{$I_{(m+1)}$} & d\\ 
    \hline
    \bar 0_n & \bar 0_{(m+1)} & 0\\ 
    \hline
 \end{array}
\] \


\[
\begin{array}{|>{\centering\bigstrut$}p{3cm}<{$}|>{\centering$}p{3cm}<{$}|c|}
  \hline
   & &\\
   \multirow{-4}{*}{$I_{(m+1)}$} && \hat b \\
    & & \\
    \cdashline{2-2} \cdashline{3-3} 
      & \bar c & d\\ 
   \hline
   \bar 0_{(m+1)} &  \bar 0_n & 0\\ 
   \hline
 \end{array}
\] \

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope I understood the question correctly.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow,array}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{bigstrut}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{|>{\centering\bigstrut$}p{3cm}<{$}|>{\centering$}p{3cm}<{$}|c|}
\hline
& &  \\
A & & \hat b \\
& &  \\
\cdashline{1-1} \cdashline{3-3} 
\bar c &\multirow{-4}{*}{$I_{(m+1)}$} & d\\ 
\hline
\bar 0_n & \bar 0_{(m+1)} & 0\\ 
\hline
\end{array}
\] \

%1st and 2nd column switched around:
\[
\begin{array}{| >{\centering$}p{3cm}<{$} | >{\centering\bigstrut$}p{3cm}<{$} | c |}
\hline
& & \\
& A & \hat b \\
& & \\
\cdashline{2-2} \cdashline{3-3} %or \cdashline{2-3}
\multirow{-4}{*}{$I_{(m+1)}$} & \bar c & d \\
\hline
\bar 0_{(m+1)} & \bar 0_n & 0 \\
\hline
\end{array}
\] \

\end{document}
```

[image]

You could do `\cdashline{2-3}` in the second one as well, but then the cline in the third column looks a bit different than in the first picture, didn't know if you need both versions or just the flipped one.

Comment: Yes! That was exactly what I was trying to do. Thanks so much!